# Opengl shadow acne when using shadow2D

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement shadow mapping  in opengl. It's working, however aliasing is visible, so I decided to use sampler2Dshadow with shadow2D, cause I've read it serves as simple anti-aliasing solution. But as soon as I use it, it causes very significant shadow acne across whole scene. Note that when using sampler2D with texture2D, there's none. 
Is this intended? If so, how should I solved it?

This is how it looks while using sampler2DShadow:
[image: 1]

This is part of fragment shader that handles shadows:

```
    float theta = clamp(dot(normalize(lightVector), normalize(vertNormal)), 0, 1);
    float bias = 0.005*tan(acos(theta));
    float visibility = 1.0;
    if ( shadow2D(shadowTex, shadowCoord).z < shadowCoord.z - bias){
        visibility = 0.5;
    }
    color = vec4(color.xyz * visibility, 1);
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, you talk about a lot of things, and the title well that is just way off. Please write some more info, show some code, what are the problems in the code, etc?

Comment: try to increase your bias value

Comment: I've tried that, It stops when bias value is 1 :/

Comment: what does stop? Anyway, that's how one usually solves the problem, by adjusting the bias.

Answer (score 9):

Why is your bias based on the angle between the light and surface? That is what is causing these bizarre moiré patterns. Usually if you want to bias the depth against angle (think of it like anisotropic bias for shadow maps) you would use `glPolygonOffset (...)` when you create the shadow map, and in your shader you would use a constant bias, or a bias that varies slightly with distance (but not angle).

The problem with polygon offset, however, is that it will disable hierarchical Z-Buffering when enabled (so shadow map construction fill-rate will theoretically dip). The offset occurs ***after*** primitive assembly. It is not a perfect solution, but definitely better than what you have right now.

You might be able to implement slope based biasing in your shadow map's vertex shader by biasing the W coordinate slightly, this will allow early Z rejection using the results of the primitive assembly stage... but it will be harder to find a good value to use for W.

---

> ... so I decided to use sampler2Dshadow with shadow2D, cause I've read it serves as simple anti-aliasing solution.

As for the difference between `sampler2D` and `sampler2DShadow`, when used in a call to `texture (...)` (*or `shadow2D (...)` in older versions of GLSL*) a `sampler2DShadow` that has texture comparison enabled will produce a binary result - **1.0** if it *passes* the test function, **0.0** if it *fails*. Considering your fragment shader already performs a comparison and expects the value returned by the sampler to be the depth, and not a ***pass/fail*** result you should be using `sampler2D` -- ignore the existence of `sampler2DShadow` in this case.

[image]

I have no idea what version of GLSL you are using, since you make use of `shadow2D (...)`, which has long been deprecated. However, if you take a look at the GLSL [specification for version 440](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf), pg. 153 (8.9 - Texture Functions) it will refer you to the table I included above.

> For shadow forms (the sampler parameter is a shadow-type), a depth comparison lookup on the depth texture bound to sampler is done as described in section 8.22 “Texture Comparison Modes” of the OpenGL Graphics System Specification. See the table below for which component specifies D<sub>ref</sub>. The texture bound to sampler must be a depth texture, or results are undefined. If a non-shadow texture call is made to a sampler that represents a depth texture with depth comparisons turned on, then results are undefined. If a shadow texture call is made to a sampler that represents a depth texture with depth comparisons turned off, then results are undefined. If a shadow texture call is made to a sampler that does not represent a depth texture, then results are undefined.

Effectively `sampler2DShadow` will reduce aliasing, but only because it produces exactly two results: **1.0** and **0.0** and the average of these results is more meaningful than the average depth (as I will explain below). So there is some truth to that statement, but you have taken it out of context I believe.

In reality, if you want to reduce shadow aliasing what you ought to do is take the average of N-many depth tests. Using linear filtering is usually a valid approach to reduce aliasing in traditional textures, but with depth textures the value stored in the texture is actually *supposed to* be used for comparison purposes. If you were to use linear filtering and `sampler2D`, the GPU would gather the 4 nearest depths in the shadow map, average them and then you would perform a single pass/fail test on the averaged depth. This actually gets you nothing useful because your fragments still either pass or fail.

What you want to do is gather the 4 nearest depths, test them individually and then average the pass/fail result. Then instead of each fragment either passing or failing, you may naively have 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% or 100% obstruction -- in fact, the average may be weighted by distance of each sample from the sample coordinate. This is known as **Percentage Closer Filtering** (PCF), `shadow2D (...)` and `sampler2DShadow` actually do exactly this if you enable linear filtering on some drivers. Instead of averaging sampled depths, they test the sampled depths and then average the results of all tests.

***This*** is actually where the anti-aliasing properties of `sampler2DShadow` come from, but you must structure your GLSL shader properly to take advantage of it. You can just as easily (and more portably) sample 4 points yourself using a `sampler2D` with a ***NEAREST*** filter and perform the testing and averaging yourself...

---

Also, try not to read the `z` component of a depth texture. You are lucky that for versions of GLSL >= 130, a sampled depth texture produces the result: `vec4 (r, r, r, 1.0)`, but in older versions of GLSL the behavior depends on something called a depth texture mode. It is equally possible for `z` to be **0.0**, or completely undefined pre-GL3. You should read `r` or `x`, since depth textures are single-component by nature. The table above even indicates this - the computed result is stored in `r`, not `b`.