# glsl sampler2DShadow and shadow2D clarification

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

Quick background of where I'm at (to make sure we're on the same page, and sanity check if I'm missing/assuming something stupid):

- Goal: I want to render my scene with shadows, using deferred lighting
  and shadowmaps.
- Struggle: finding clear and consistent documentation regarding how to use shadow2D and sampler2DShadow.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

In the fragment shader of my final rendering pass (the one that actually calculates final frag values), I have the MVP matrices from the pass from the light's point of view, the depth texture from said pass (aka the "shadow map"), and the position/normal/color textures from my geometry buffer.

From what I understand, I need to find what UV of the shadow map the position of the current fragment corresponds to. I do that by the following:

```
//Bring position value at fragment (in world space) to screen space from lights POV
vec4 UVinShadowMap = (lightProjMat * lightViewMat * vec4(texture(pos_tex, UV).xyz,1.0)).xy; 
//Convert screen space to 'texture space' (from -1to1 to 0to1)
UVinShadowMap = (UVinShadowMap+1)/2;
```

Now that I have this UV, I can get the percieved 'depth' from the light's pov with

```
float depFromLightPOV = texture2D(shadowMap, UVinShadowMap).r;
```

and compare that against the distance between the position at the current fragment and the light:

```
float actualDistance = distance(texture2D(pos_tex, UV).xyz, lightPos);
```

The problem comes from that 'depth' is stored in values 0-1, and actual distance is in world coordinates. I've tried to do that conversion manually, but couldn't get it to work. And in searching online, it looks like the way I SHOULD be doing this is with a sampler2DShadow...

---

**So here's my question(s):**

What changes do I need to make to instead use shadow2D? What does shadow2D even do? Is it just more-or-less an auto-conversion-from-depth-to-world texture? Can I use the same depth texture? Or do I need to render the depth texture a different way? What do I pass in to shadow2D? The world-space position of the fragment I want to check? Or the same UV as before?

If all these questions can be answered in a simple documentation page, I'd love if someone could just post that. But I swear I've been searching for hours and can't find anything that simply says what the heck is going on with shadow2D!

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516538/opengl-shadow-acne-when-using-shadow2d since it explains many of the things you are asking about.

Comment: I think this one is closer (and together with the wiki link in the answer should address your questions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877938/glsl-sampler2dshadow-deprecated-past-version-120-what-to-use (note that the question title is misleading - sampler2dshadow is not deprecated)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

#### First of all, what version of GLSL are you using?

Beginning with GLSL 1.30, there is no special texture lookup function (name anyway) for use with `sampler2DShadow`. GLSL 1.30+ uses a bunch of overloads of `texture (...)` that are selected based on the type of `sampler` passed and the dimensions of the coordinates.

#### Second, if you do use `sampler2DShadow` you need to do two things differently:

1. Texture comparison must be enabled or you will get undefined results

   - `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE` = `GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE​`
2. The coordinates you pass to `texture (...)` are 3D instead of 2D. The new 3rd coordinate is the depth value that you are going to compare.

#### Last, you should understand what `texture (...)` returns when using `sampler2DShadow`:

If this comparison passes, `texture (...)` will return **1.0**, if it fails it will return **0.0**. If you use a `GL_LINEAR` texture filter on your depth texture, then `texture (...)` will perform 4 depth comparisons using the 4 closest depth values in your depth texture and return a value somewhere *in-between* **1.0** and **0.0** to give an idea of the number of samples that passed/failed.

That is the proper way to do hardware anti-aliasing of shadow maps. If you tried to use a regular `sampler2D` with `GL_LINEAR` and implement the depth test yourself you would get a single averaged depth back and a boolean pass/fail result instead of the behavior described above for `sampler2DShadow`.

---

As for getting a depth value to test from a world-space position, you were on the right track (though you forgot perspective division).

#### There are three things you must do to generate a depth from a world-space position:

1. Multiply the world-space position by your (light's) projection and view matrices
2. Divide the resulting coordinate by its `W` component
3. Scale and bias the result (which will be in the range [-1,1]) into the range [0,1]

*The final step assumes you are using the default depth range... if you have not called `glDepthRange (...)` then this will work.*

The end result of step 3 serves as ***both*** a **depth** value (`R`) and **texture coordinates** (`ST`) for lookup into your depth map. This makes it possible to pass this value ***directly*** to `texture (...)`. Recall that the first 2 components of the texture coordinates are the same as always, and that the 3rd is a depth value to test.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to just comment "Thank you" but seriously- THANK YOU! I've been struggling with this for like a month, and this post finally tipped me over the slump! Clear, concise, all in one place. Brilliant. :)

Comment: How come then textureLod(sampler2DShadow) call needs a vec4 for the p parameter? I was expecting (uv, depth) ... what do you do with a vec4?

Comment: Be careful using both sampler2D and sampler2DShadow in the same shader. They cannot be binded to the same texture unit. You also HAVE TO initialize sampler2DShadow if use a shader that declares it (regardless of actually using it or not). The reason being by default, it gets unit 0 and depending on driver, OpenGL will give you a warning saying texture 0 is not a depth texture yet you are using sampler2DShadow. While this is safe to ignore, it is still good practice to make sure it is initialized.

Comment: And what fragment shader I have to use if I just want to visualize depth map with ```GL_LINEAR```texture filter? I mean I don't need shadows, but only visualize depth using ```sampler2DShadow```.