# opengl framebuffer depth texture not working

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, depth, depth-buffer

I've been trying to get shadow mapping to work , but the the depth isn't even writing to the texture . Here's my code .

```
//this is outside the main loop to generate the depth texture and the framebuffer
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

GLuint depthTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024,1024,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0); 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0);       
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLuint FramebufferName ;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER , FramebufferName);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER , 0);


/////////////////this is inside the loop
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER , FramebufferName);

glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0,0,1024,1024);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
  cout<<" WARNING !! ";


Matrix DephtViewMatrix = IDENTITY_MATRIX;
DephtViewMatrix = MultiplyMatrices(DephtViewMatrix , TRANSLATION_MATRIX(0,-25,0));  //my own math header
DephtViewMatrix = MultiplyMatrices(DephtViewMatrix , XROTATION_MATRIX(-1.6));
shadow.UseProgram();
shadow.CreateProjection(60,1024,1024,0.1 ,70);//also tried to change to orthographic projection , but it didn't help 
shadow.setMVP(DephtViewMatrix , IDENTITY_MATRIX);

sphere.draws();
terrain.draws();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER ,0);

//vetrex shader
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec3 in_Position;

uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

void main(void)
{   
   gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * vec4(in_Position.xyz ,1) ;

 }

//fragment shader

#version 330

layout(location = 0) out float depth;

void main()
{
    depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

I'm drawing the texture on a cube , the scene draws correctly when drawing it with colors .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please edit your question to show the shader you are using to ***sample*** the depth texture?

Immediately, I notice that you have texture comparison set to `GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE`; this means that unless you sample the texture using `sampler2DShadow`, `samplerCubeShadow`, etc. that the results will be undefined. Textures with comparison mode != `GL_NONE` must be sampled using a `...Shadow` sampler, likewise textures with comparison mode == `GL_NONE` must **not** be sampled with a `...Shadow` sampler.

And even if you use the appropriate sampler type for your depth texture, if you have texture comparison enabled then the result of sampling the texture is going to be a binary pass/fail (**1.0** or **0.0**) result of performing a depth test on the stored depth, rather than the depth itself. You really cannot visualize the depth stored in a shadow map using texture comparison. But the good news is that you can change the comparison mode on-the-fly depending on how you intend to use the depth texture, it just needs to match your sampler type in the shader you are using.

You might want to take a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419682/glsl-sampler2dshadow-and-shadow2d-clarification/22426507#22426507) that I wrote, which explains the differences between shadow and non-shadow samplers.