# Shadow mapping with a deferred rendering

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping, deferred-rendering

I am trying to implement a shadow mapping technique and I have some problems to make it works.

I have a camera in the light's position and this is the shadow map I get. All the vertex have been multiplied by each `modelViewProjectionMatrix`.

[image: Camera light's view]

I also have a texture with the world positions of the vertex. It's a `GL_RGBA32F` texture because all the points have been multiplied by each `ModelMatrix` to have the points in world space.

[image]

And the shader:

```
layout(binding=5) uniform sampler2D shadowMap;
layout(binding=6) uniform sampler2D positionMap;

in vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat uViewProjectionMatrix;

out vec4 color;

void main() {

   vec4 pos = texture(positionMap, texcoord);

   vec4 ShadowCoord = uViewProjectionMatrix * pos;
   ShadowCoord.xy = ShadowCoord.xy * vec2(0.5,0.5) + vec2(0.5,0.5);

   float a = texture(shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy).z;
   color = vec4(a, a, a, 1.0);
}
```

The output (the camera is almost in the same position of the light):

[image]

I am just trying to see if the projection of each vertex is right from the camera's position but looks like it's not.
The point of all this is to compare:

```
if ( texture(shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy).z <  ( ShadowCoord.z-bias ) )
```

but it also doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You are missing the perspective divide and you seem to be completely ignoring depth range.

The general idea here is to get `ShadowCoord.xyz` into the range [**0**,**1**] (for texture lookup and depth comparison). Your code operates under the assumption that `uViewProjectionMatrix * pos` (clip-space coordinates) is in the range [**-1**,**1**] but that is not really guaranteed unless you divide by `w` (NDC coordinates).

#### I would consider something like this instead:

```
void main() {
  vec4 pos = texture(positionMap, texcoord);

  vec4 ShadowCoord = uViewProjectionMatrix * pos;
  ShadowCoord /= ShadowCoord.w;

  ShadowCoord.xyz = ShadowCoord.xyz * vec3 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) + vec2 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

  float a = texture(shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy).z;
  color = vec4(a, a, a, 1.0);
}
```

After this, `ShadowCoord.xy` will be a texture coordinate to lookup in your shadow map, and `ShadowCoord.z` will be the current fragment's depth from your light's point of view. You can use `ShadowCoord.z` for comparison versus the sampled depth.

In fact, you might even consider using a `sampler2DShadow` to do this more efficiently. For an example of that, see [this related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419682/glsl-sampler2dshadow-and-shadow2d-clarification/22426507#22426507)

Comment: In case it was not clear in the answer, I also adjusted your code so that it scales and biases the clip-space `z` coordinate into the range [**0**,**1**] (from [**-1**,**1**]). The value fetched from the shadow map is going to be in [**0**,**1**] so you cannot ignore that step. You need to do it for `xyz`, not just `xy` like you were originally.

Comment: A 'gotcha' with sampler2DShadow is that is samples using nearest even if linear is used for the min/mag filters. This can be confusing if you were looking to reduce shadow acne by utilizing linear interpolation on the shadow map depth. See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88187/c-opengl-shadowmap-issue-artifacts

Comment: @PaulRenton: Indeed, what it actually interpolates is the result of the 4 binary pass/fail depth tests for the 4 nearest neighbor depth samples. That's explained in the answer I linked to.

Comment: Wow! That was the problem. I have already tried to divide by w but I forgot to do the multiplication and the addition in the z component... so when i compared the depths... weird things happened.

Thank you very much for your time.